# How does Weka evaluate classifier model

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I used random forest algorithm and got this result

```
=== Summary ===

Correctly Classified Instances       10547               97.0464 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances       321                2.9536 %
Kappa statistic                          0.9642
Mean absolute error                      0.0333
Root mean squared error                  0.0952
Relative absolute error                 18.1436 %
Root relative squared error             31.4285 %
Total Number of Instances            10868

=== Confusion Matrix ===

    a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i   <-- classified as
 1518    1    3    1    0   14    0    0    4 |    a = a
    3 2446    0    0    0    1    1   27    0 |    b = b
    0    0 2942    0    0    0    0    0    0 |    c = c
    0    0    0  470    0    1    1    2    1 |    d = d
    9    0    0    9    2   19    0    3    0 |    e = e
   23    1    2   19    0  677    1   22    6 |    f = f
    4    0    2    0    0   13  379    0    0 |    g = g
   63    2    6   17    0   15    0 1122    3 |    h = h
    9    0    0    0    0    9    0    4  991 |    i = i
```

I wonder how Weka evaluate errors(mean absolute error, root mean squared error, ...) using non numerical values('a', 'b', ...).

I mapped each classes to numbers from 0 to 8 and evaluated errors manually, but the evaluation was different from Weka.

How to reimplemen the evaluating steps of Weka?

Comment: You don't provide enough information. For starters, did you do a  test-set/training-set split? or did you do, say, 10-fold cross validation?

Comment: @knb I used 10-fold cross validation